# C++ two template keywords on one function

Tags: c++, templates

Observing `random.tcc` STL source file found the following operator definition:

```
  template<typename _IntType>
    template<typename _UniformRandomNumberGenerator>
      typename geometric_distribution<_IntType>::result_type
      geometric_distribution<_IntType>::
      operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator& __urng,
         const param_type& __param)
      {
    // About the epsilon thing see this thread:
    // http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2006-10/msg00971.html
    const double __naf =
      (1 - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) / 2;
    // The largest _RealType convertible to _IntType.
    const double __thr =
      std::numeric_limits<_IntType>::max() + __naf;
    __detail::_Adaptor<_UniformRandomNumberGenerator, double>
      __aurng(__urng);

    double __cand;
    do
      __cand = std::floor(std::log(1.0 - __aurng()) / __param._M_log_1_p);
    while (__cand >= __thr);

    return result_type(__cand + __naf);
      }
```

Google and various C++ references didn't help me understand what it means when there are two `template` declarations in a row. Please help who knows.

Comment: It is a definition of templated method for templated class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a template inside a template.

Easier to see from the declaration which probably looked something like this

```
template<typename _IntType>
class geometric_distribution
{
    ...
    template<typename _UniformRandomNumberGenerator>
    result_type operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator& __urng, const param_type& __param);
    ...
};
```

Comment: Yes, there's a definition in `random.h`: `template<typename _IntType = int> class geometric_distribution  {...`. Thanks!